# Is there a way to make formulas in Excel, inserted via SQL query, automatically become equations without manually refreshing each field?

Tags: sql-server, excel, excel-formula

When I use SQL to create a hyperlink field in Excel, it doesn't automatically add it as a hyperlink when using a SQL query from Excel (pasting it in from SSMS works perfectly though).

Here is the specific line of code that I use to make that field (with field names changed to some standard template):

```
 CONCAT('=HYPERLINK(', '"linktexthere=',[tablename].[fieldname],'",','"',[tablename].[fieldname],' ',[tablename].[fieldname],'"',')') AS 'alias'
```

Here is my full script for anyone who wants to tear me a new one regarding anything that I do in it.

```
USE DBNAME;

SELECT 
    FORMAT([fieldName], 'd', 'en-us') AS 'Alias',
    [fieldName] AS 'Alias', 
    [fieldName] AS 'Alias', 
    [fieldName] AS 'Alias',
    tableName.fieldName AS 'Alias',
    CONCAT('=HYPERLINK(', '"linktexthere=',[tablename].[fieldname],'",','"',[tablename].[fieldname],' ',[tablename].[fieldname],'"',')') AS 'alias' 
FROM 
    tableName WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN 
    tableName WITH (NOLOCK) ON tableName.fieldName = tableName.fieldName
INNER JOIN 
    tableName WITH (NOLOCK) on tableName.fieldName = tableName.fieldName
WHERE
    MONTH([fieldName]) = MONTH(DATEADD(M, -1, GETDATE())) 
    AND YEAR([fieldName]) = YEAR(DATEADD(M, -1, GETDATE())) 
    AND [tableName].[fieldName] NOT LIKE '%textHere%'
ORDER BY
    [Alias]
```

The SQL runs fine and the hyperlink equation gets created successfully BUT the field in Excel looks like

```
=HYPERLINK("linktexthere","tablename.fieldname")
```

until I enter the field and then exit out of it... in which it looks like `tablename.fieldname`

Any ideas on how to make it automatically refresh fields without vba? This is a report that is going to be used by people who are less technical and won't have access to just copy/paste from SSMS.

ALSO any advice on making questions on here? I'm probably going to start making more of them and I want to make people less angry while reading my posts!

EDIT 1: Formatting/New poster corrections (Thanks Marc!)

EDIT 2:
I've gotten this to work with VBA through a button (using Worksheet.Calculate works as well),

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim i As Long: i = 0
'
' Button1_Click Macro
' used to refresh data and set all of it back to normal
'
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:5"))
    Range("F1").Select
    For i = 1 To Rows.Count
    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 6).Value) Then
    Application.SendKeys ("{F2}{Enter}")
    End If
    Next i
    Application.SendKeys ("{F2}{Enter}")
    
End Sub
```

This doesn't necessarily answer my question, and the solution is quite disgusting, but this is the way I've gotten it to work so far. Any better advice would be great.

Comment: You could possibly do it through the `Worksheet_Calculate` event?

Comment: I will test it when I get into work in the morning to see if I can get it to work that way... Preferably trying to not use VBA, the last thing I need to do is train my users to click enable content in an already heavy spear phishing environment lol.

Comment: See [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: Haha. Thanks Marc... especially for something as small as this. I still get tiny panic moments from my last job where it was vba driven sql and everything would lock up if you attempted to run adhoc queries. I'll definitely look into implementing an alternative... as it is "dated" data (month before), I could probably make a task to just insert it into a temp view on an off day and drop it the following week after it's run.

Comment: @DanDonoghue -- Thank you for the push... Edit 2 has what I did via vba, its kind of odd but normal refreshing doesn't do anything. Only manually refreshing each cell seems to do the trick...